# django-allauth - show user email address in confirmation email

Tags: django-allauth

I am sending out user sign-up/confirmation emails (django_allauth), and customising the templates for this function. Everything is working, emails are sent out, correct templates are being used, users can click links and confirm addresses, etc.

However, I would like to be able to display the email address in the confirmation email, ie something like:

`The {{ user_name }} wants to confirm the email address {{ email_address }}…`

It seems to me to be obvious that django_allauth "knows" the email address, since it is handling the sending/confirmation, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation as to how to access that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this issue for a LONG TIME, and there didn't seem to be any sources on the internet that could help me! But, it's actually really simple.

```
{{ user.email }}
```

will get you the user email. The default implementation for getting the username is

```
{% user_display user %}
```

, but I'm guessing you can also use `{{ user.username }}`

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#account-tags explains some of it. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I noticed that it only works within the html files, such as account/email/email_confirmation_message.html. I don't know why it doesn't work within the .txt files :(.

Comment: No, I see different behaviour, the examples you give display in a response HTML page, but don’t display in email sent (either HTML or plain text, ie email_confirmation_message.html or email_confirmation_message.txt).